# Accessing the user's request in a post_save signal

Tags: python, django, signals

I have done the below post_save signal in my project.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# CORE - SIGNALS
# Core Signals will operate based on post

def after_save_handler_attr_audit_obj(sender, **kwargs):
    print User.get_profile()

    if hasattr(kwargs['instance'], 'audit_obj'):
        if kwargs['created']:
            kwargs['instance'].audit_obj.create(operation="INSERT", operation_by=**USER.ID**).save()
        else:
            kwargs['instance'].audit_obj.create(operation="UPDATE").save()


# Connect the handler with the post save signal - Django 1.2
post_save.connect(after_save_handler_attr_audit_obj, dispatch_uid="core.models.audit.new")
```

The operation_by column, I want to get the user_id and store it. Any idea how can do that?

Comment: There is a reason why django does not want you to access request object in models and signals. Its philosophy of separation of concerns will be violated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Can't be done. The current user is only available via the request, which is not available when using purely model functionality. Access the user in the view somehow.

Comment: hmm It make sense, I just reformatted my question to find out a way to do the job using alternative methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725685/django-auto-filling-some-data-based-on-model-attribute

Comment: You can do it when loading your view. In your post_save save the status you want to flag in the model. When loading the model in the view, check the status flag and do what you will with it before response.  I do an api call post status, then set a model field called api_status with the appropriate status code. I check the code in my get and use the messages framework to notify the user of the status received from the call.

Comment: I am using `post_save`. The model which is saving the data has a field called `user`. I am using `instance.user` to target the user. However, the condition over here is that no user can edit other user's instances. Thus, the logged in user is equal to the `instance.user` value.

Answer (score 13):

You can do that with the help of middleware. Create `get_request.py` in your app. Then

```
from threading import current_thread

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


_requests = {}


def current_request():
    return _requests.get(current_thread().ident, None)


class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread().ident] = request

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # when response is ready, request should be flushed
        _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
        return response


    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # if an exception has happened, request should be flushed too
         _requests.pop(current_thread().ident, None)
```

Then add this middleware to your settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ....
    '<your_app>.get_request.RequestMiddleware',
]
```

Then add import to your signals:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from <your_app>.get_request import current_request

# CORE - SIGNALS
# Core Signals will operate based on post

def after_save_handler_attr_audit_obj(sender, **kwargs):
    print(Current User, current_request().user)
    print User.get_profile()

    if hasattr(kwargs['instance'], 'audit_obj'):
        if kwargs['created']:
            kwargs['instance'].audit_obj.create(operation="INSERT", operation_by=**USER.ID**).save()
        else:
            kwargs['instance'].audit_obj.create(operation="UPDATE").save()


# Connect the handler with the post save signal - Django 1.2
post_save.connect(after_save_handler_attr_audit_obj, dispatch_uid="core.models.audit.new")
```

Comment: Any downside to this method? I use it and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to do it by inspecting the stack and looking for the view then looking at the local variables for the view to get the request. It feels like a bit of a hack, but it worked.

```
import inspect, os

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def get_user_in_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    for entry in reversed(inspect.stack()):
        if os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/views.py' == entry[1]:
            try:
                user = entry[0].f_locals['request'].user
            except:
                user = None
            break
    if user:
        # do stuff with the user variable
```

Comment: worked great for me, I didn't know what the view would be so I removed that check and it still worked fine.

Comment: It's not "right" but it works great, so I think this is the right answer.

Comment: very hacky solution, downvote because it's a very bad practice

Comment: This does't work for me. Getting KeyError at /api/ 'request'

Comment: It might work sometimes, but it's an extreme hack and not meant to be used: downvote.

Comment: DJango is under no obligation to maintain the stack trace compatible with this approach. This code could break at any update really. Nice try, but downvoted as well.

Answer (score 9):

Ignacio is right. Django's model signals are intended to notify other system components about events associated with instances and their respected data, so I guess it's valid that you cannot, say, access request data from a model `post_save` signal, unless that request data was stored on or associated with the instance.

I guess there are lots of ways to handle it, ranging from worse to better, but I'd say this is a *prime* example for creating class-based/function-based generic views that will automatically handle this for you.

Have your views that inherit from `CreateView`, `UpdateView` or `DeleteView` additionally inherit from your `AuditMixin` class if they handle verbs that operate on models that need to be audited. The `AuditMixin` can then hook into the views that successfully create\update\delete objects and create an entry in the database.

Makes perfect sense, very clean, easily pluggable and gives birth to happy ponies. Flipside? You'll either have to be on the soon-to-be-released Django 1.3 release or you'll have to spend some time fiddlebending the function-based generic views and providing new ones for each auditing operation.

Comment: Timeless answer

Answer (score 7):

Why not adding a middleware with something like this :

```
class RequestMiddleware(object):

    thread_local = threading.local()

    def process_request(self, request):
        RequestMiddleware.thread_local.current_user = request.user
```

and later in your code (specially in a signal in that topic) :

```
thread_local = RequestMiddleware.thread_local
if hasattr(thread_local, 'current_user'):
    user = thread_local.current_user
else:
    user = None
```

Comment: Sounds clean approach. I want to find out how expensive is this.

Comment: I would advise against using threading for this. This is feel very hacky, and is not application level code, since you don't have much control of those threads. I would use the cache as a communication backend here using a unique ID.

Comment: @electropoet did you find out how expensive is it? I'm thinking of implementing it as well, and so far i can not think of any side effects.

Comment: I used it, works badly. Probably it's because one thread can process several requests.

Comment: @MarkMishyn do you imply that `current_user` can be overwritten by another request while the original request hasn't finished yet?

Comment: @EugeneKovalev Yes, I imply this scenario.

Answer (score 6):

For traceability add two attributes to your Model(`created_by` and `updated_by`), in "updated_by" save the last user who modified the record. Then in your signal you have the user:

models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    created_by = models. (max_length=100)
    updated_by = models. (max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
    p = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
    p.question_text = 'some new text'
    p.updated_by = request.user
    p.save()
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Question)
def do_something(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = Question.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        if not obj.user == instance.user: # Field has changed
            # do something
            print('change: user, old=%s new=%s' % (obj.user, instance.user))
```

Comment: This is terribly prone to race conditions. Which might be ok for a lot of use-cases, but it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use django-reversion for this purpose, e.g.

```
from reversion.signals import post_revision_commit
import reversion

@receiver(post_save)
def post_revision_commit(sender, **kwargs):
    if reversion.is_active():
        print(reversion.get_user())
```

Read more on their API https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#revision-api

Answer (score 4):

You can do a small hack by overriding you model `save()` method and setting the user on the saved instance as additional parameter. To get the user I used `get_current_authenticated_user()` from `django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware` (see https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/).

In your `models.py`:

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import get_current_authenticated_user

class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Hack to pass the user to post save signal.
        self.current_authenticated_user = get_current_authenticated_user()
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your `signals.py`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def your_model_saved(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = getattr(instance, 'current_authenticated_user', None)
```

PS: Don't forget to add `'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: That feels too hacky and will appear like black magic in the other app that's consuming the signal (accessing a field that doesn't exist in the model definition).

Comment: That are the words from which the post starts: "You can do a small hack".
Hack is hack, it can solve certain problem. Just be careful with it or find better and safer solution.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you would have figured this out, but I had the same problem and I realised that **all the instances I create had a reference to the user that creates them** (which is what you are looking for)

Comment: Could you elaborate? How come:"all the instances I create had a reference to the user that creates them"?

Comment: What I mean is that all the signals I use has reference to an instance (in the kwargs) that has a field 'created_by' or something similar, that refers to the user.

Comment: beautiful, just beautiful

Answer (score 0):

it's possible i guess.

in models.py

```
class _M(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

in views.py

```
def _f(request):
    _M.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

in signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=_M)
def _p(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   user = instance.user
```

No ?

Answer (score 0):

**Request object can be obtained from frame record by inspecting.**

```
import inspect

request = [
    frame_record[0].f_locals["request"]
    for frame_record in inspect.stack()
    if frame_record[3] == "get_response"
][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_requested_user():
    import inspect
    for frame_record in inspect.stack():
        if frame_record[3] == 'get_response':
            request = frame_record[0].f_locals['request']
            return request.user
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -4):

```
context_processors.py

from django.core.cache import cache

def global_variables(request):
    cache.set('user', request.user)

----------------------------------
in you model

from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.cache import cache
from news.models import News

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=News)
def news_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = cache.get('user')

in settings.py

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'web.context_processors.global_variables',
)
```

Comment: A description of what you did there would be helpful.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, never do it this way. With most cache configurations this is gonna lead to race condition.

Comment: This is totally WRONG. cache is not request specific

Comment: Just a note, this is not necessarily a bad idea if you give a unique id as a key.
My use-case is to add meta data from the request to an instance that is created via a signal, but needs data from the request.
I dislike the idea of coupling this with a specific process.
I would use the users PK field as `user_{pk}` and access it's metadata. this shouldn't create a race condition, and gives the intended result.