# django auto filling some data based on model attribute

Tags: python, django

am working on a concept in which I want to capture certain information when a model is saved. To understand the full picture, I have a app core with the following model

core/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from transmeta import TransMeta
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

import signals


class Audit(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    # Polymorphic model using generic relation through DJANGO content type
    operation  = models.CharField(_('Operation'), max_length=40)
    operation_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Operation At'), auto_now_add=True)
    operation_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_y+")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Audit model is a generic content type, am currently attaching it with other apps such as in blog

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
# Create your models here.



    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

class article(models.Model):
    title            = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug             = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique_for_year=True)
    content          = models.TextField()
    is_active        = models.BooleanField()
    published_at     = models.DateTimeField('Publish at',auto_now=True)
    related_articles = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
    audit_obj        = generic.GenericRelation('core.Audit', editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

My first attempt was, I made a post_save signal in which I was checking if the instance passed containing audit_obj attribute and then saving a record in using `article.audit_obj.create().save()`.

Unfortunately, this did not entirely work out for me since I cannot pass the request nor I can access the request to retrieve the user information.

So, I was thinking to create a custom signal and override the form_save method (if there is such a thing) and then using arguments to pass the request object as well as the model object.

Any advice on how I can do that?

Regards,

**EDIT (20th of Jan, 2011):**

Thanks @Yuji for your time. Well, what am trying to achieve is to keep my code as DRY as possible. What I want to do ultimately, every time I create new model, I will only create an additional attribute and name it audit_obj and I will create a single piece of code, either a signal or to override the save method inside the django core itself. The peiece of code will always check if an attribute with the following name exists and therefore creates a record in aduti table.

Comment: Hey Mo J., it's absolutely bizarre that I was googling a similar problem and was reading your original post (different SO question), clicked on a link, and read my name in the post. Hope that's been working for ya!

Answer (score 3):

I'd just create a function in my model class or Manager and call it from my form save (wherever yours might be)

```
class AuditManager(models.Manager):
    def save_from_object(self, request, obj):
        audit = Audit()
        audit.object_id = obj.id
        audit.operation_by = request.user
        # ...

        audit.save()


class Audit(models.Model):
    ## TODO: Document
    # Polymorphic model using generic relation through DJANGO content type
    operation  = models.CharField(_('Operation'), max_length=40)
    operation_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Operation At'), auto_now_add=True)
    operation_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_y+")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    objects = AuditManager()


class MyBlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = article # btw I'd use Capital Letters For Classes

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyBlogForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        Audit.objects.save_from_object(request, self.instance)
```

Comment: this will work out too. But, I will have to repeat this piece of code at every model with audit_obj. The way I was thinking about it is to create a single listener/signal or override the form save method to check at every action if the method contain a audit_obj attribute and then create a record in Audit class.

Comment: Can you explain the "or override the form save method" part? Isn't this exactly overriding the form save method? I think the only way to make it more DRY is to subclass ModelForm with an overridden save and to use that in all your forms. Creating a signal for each form is the same work as calling a function (my example). There is no default form save signal, so you'd have to define it anyways.

Comment: Thanks Yuji, I just made an edit to my original question for more clarification.

Comment: I see, that's much clearer. In that case, you could hack ModelForms save method to check for an attribute in the relevant model class (or perhaps `form` if you will have non modelforms and enforce the passing of request into the form constructor IF the model/form has audit=True. I really dislike that idea though, at the very least you should subclass ModelForms instead of modifying it itself!