# User Object in Django Signals

Tags: django, signals, django-signals

I am using `.post_save` in some of my models to do some time consuming works. I want to track which user is actually sending the signals. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This is actually not possible. Compare [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716440/4344683).

Answer (score 0):

one solution is put user like a field of the model that you are saving `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` to use after in the signal.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_saved(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # here, instance is the User instance that was saved in the database
    time_consuming_work(instance)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not think this is what the OP was referring to. The question was about the `request.user` if you so will