# Get current user in tasks.py Celery-Django

Tags: python, django, request, task, celery

I'm using Celery in a Django project and I'm trying to get the current user in file tasks.py. I don't want to use "User.objects.get(id)" because I can't pass an argument (id) to the function. Is there something similar to "request.user" that I can use?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A task has no user, or at least not a user like a request. A task can run onder an OS user, but that is a different set of users.

Comment: So there is no way to get the user without using User.objects.get?

Comment: @Biniik: even `User.objects.get(..)` will not retrieve anything. What `id` would you pass? There is no "current user" in a task that is triggered through a management command/celery.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Well, if I use task.delay() in some view I could pass the id of the user logged in. But it's not the idea that I have. Anyway, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following post and scroll down to the answer. Just use the middleware in your task instead of a signal. I am doing this for user notifications where the task speaks to the WebSocket group defined by the user pk on a post_save signal:

Post:

> [Accessing the user's request in a post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716330/accessing-the-users-request-in-a-post-save-signal)

Answer:

> You can do that with the help of middleware. Create get_request.py in
> your app. Then

Comment: This doesn't really address being able to access a request User in a Celery task. If there's no user in the first place, how would you identify that a certain task is being performed by Celery in either the middleware or a Signal?