# Know if signal is triggered from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I need to send a mail only when the model is saved from django admin, I was trying with `sender.user.is_superuser` but i couldn't find the specific method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a signal, but you can do it with your `ModelAdmin`'s [`save_model()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

For example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        send_mail(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Not Possible:

[Accessing the user's request in a post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716330/accessing-the-users-request-in-a-post-save-signal)

> "Can't be done. The current user is only available via the request, which is not available when using purely model functionality. Access the user in the view somehow."
>
> "Django's model signals are intended to notify other system components about events associated with instances and their respected data"

### Possible Solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35145746/3466907