# How to get a request in post_save function

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Hello I am using Post_save signal for sending a notification from the model ....

But I am getting an error like this "sending_notification() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
"

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Plan)
def sending_notification(request, sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        notify.send(request.user, recipient = request.user, verb = "Some messages")
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access **request** there, Remove **request** from signal params.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Plan)
def sending_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        pass
```

I see what you are trying to achieve here, you are using django-notifications-hq to send a notification to users, you can do this in the view itself as **request** won't be available in model signals.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716440/8105570